Why the spark Dataframes appears empty after using delete write operation in ES from spark although DataFrames are immutable in nature?
I am using Pyspark to delete a document in ElasticIndex and here is the code.
df_users = spark.read.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').option('es.nodes', host).option('es.port', port).option('es.net.http.auth.user', un).option('es.net.http.auth.pass', pwd).option('es.net.ssl', ssl_flag).option('es.nodes.wan.only', 'true').option('es.query', es_query).load(index)

df_delete_data= consider reading data from mysql

resultant_data= df_users.select('id').intersect(df_delete_data.select('id')
resultant_data.show(truncate=False)
if resultant_data.rdd.isEmpty():
    print("skipping delete...")
else:
    resultant_data.write.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').option('es.nodes', host).option('es.batch.size.entries', 2000).option('es.resource', index).option('es.mapping.id', 'id').option('es.net.http.auth.user', un).option('es.net.http.auth.pass', pwd).option('es.net.ssl',ssl_flag) .option('es.nodes.wan.only', 'true').option('es.port', es_port).option('es.write.operation', 'delete').mode("append").save()

    resultant_data.show(truncate=False)

The above code is the example which reads data from ES and mysql and delete the records in ES based on the intersection. But my question is why the resultant_data.show(truncate=False) in the else part shows empty results since the Dataframe is immutable. I'm kinda confusion here. I know spark is lazy but there are few actions applied like .show() and .isEmpty() for the resultant_data before the delete operation. Here is the one thing if we use cache() or persist(), it works fine for me. But I just want to know why it is behaving like this and where my understanding is wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...
